# I can't open dialog box

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

This is javascript code :

```
$(function () {
  $( "#dialog1" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false
  });

  $("#opener").click(function() {
    $("#dialog1").dialog('open');
  });
});
```

This is my HTML code:
`<button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog1" title="Dialog Title" hidden="hidden">I'm a dialog</div>`

Comment: This is my `HTML Code`? Please add `html` code too.

Comment: Sorry @randomSoul Edited !

Answer (score 0):

Your code work -

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog1").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
  });

  $("#opener").click(function() {
    $("#dialog1").dialog('open');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog1" title="Dialog Title" hidden="hidden">I'm a dialog</div>
```

Comment: runcode snippet its running but in my web page nothing happens !When i click the button help me!

Comment: @VinoNagu - Do you get any errors in browser `console`? Make sure you have added file `jquery-ui.js` and is place after the `jquery.js` file.